# Can't access div element injected by Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I am trying to access a div, which is injected in the DOM by Angular app on the page.

Following is my script located at the end of the HTML page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var targetNode = document.querySelector(".navigation");

console.log(targetNode);

});
```

But when I load the page in browser, `targetNode` returns `null`.

Interesting thing here is if I run following expression in the console, it does return the `div` element that I am looking for.

```
document.querySelector(".navigation");
```

Comment: Is this Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: @illdapt It's AngularJS

Comment: FIrst make sure if the .navigation exists in your DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add a setTimeout or try to use renderer, element ref, or @viewchild... The dom u are looking for is not there when u are running ur code try using angular hooks instead of jquery.

Answer (score -1):

try `document.querySelectorAll(".navigation")` instead of `document.querySelector(".navigation")`

Comment: Didn't make any difference.